# Keep getting Attempt to execute non-instruction at 0x00400098

Tags: mips, qtspim

```
.data
scores : .word 84 99 92 45 55 46 78 67 79
arraySize : .word 9
prompt1: .asciiz "Pleaes input a passing score(between 0 and 100) : "
prompt2: .asciiz "The number of students who passed this course is : "
.text

main:
li $v0,4
la $a0,prompt1 #it will print prompt
syscall
li $v0,5
syscall #ask user input
move $s2,$v0 #move to s2
la $s0,scores #get user address
lw $s1,arraySize #get array size

li $t7,0 #store passed count

li $t0,0
loop:
mul $t1,$t0,4
add $t1,$t1,$s0
lw $t1,($t1)
blt $t1,$s2,skipCount
add $t7,$t7,1 #increase count by one
skipCount:
add $t0,$t0,1
blt $t0,$s1,loop #loop until i<size


li $v0,4
la $a0,prompt2 #it will print prompt
syscall
li $v0,1
move $a0,$t7
syscall
```

This code is meant to find the number of scores which are equal to or higher than the passing score. It asks the user for the passing score and then gives the number.

i.e. if the list of scores is: 84, 99, 92, 45, 55, 46, 78, 67, 79

If the passing score is 60, then the answer is 6. However, when I complie it, it give me the correct answer followed by "Attempt to execute non-instruction at 0x00400098"

What going on?

Comment: What were you expecting to happen after that final `syscall`?  You've done nothing to stop further execution, but there's no code after that point to be executed.

Comment: how would I terminate the program?

Comment: System call 10 works in all common MIPS simulators.